# How to update git version 2.32.0 (Apple Git-132) without Homebrew

Tags: git

I would like to simply update the git version already installed in my Macbook Pro which is:

**git version 2.32.0 (Apple Git-132)**

I do NOT wish to reinstall a new version of git with Homebrew; I would just like to update the above mentioned already existing version of git installed in my mac.

Can you help? (thank you)

Comment: You cannot "update" Apple Git. It belongs, by definition, to Apple! It might be updated when Xcode or the Xcode tools is updated; if not, not. Installing your own Git _is_ how to update. — The question is a self-contradiction; do not prescribe what the answer can and cannot be, since if you knew that, you would not be asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

The version of Git you're mentioning is shipped with XCode or the XCode Developer Tools, and it's built and shipped only as part of that by Apple.  You can try to install a newer version of whichever of those programs you've installed, but otherwise, there's no way to force them to be updated.  Apple will ship a new version if and when it pleases.

If you want a newer version than Apple provides currently, then you'll have to use another source for it.  Homebrew is simply one option among many, but it's of course a recommended one.  You could also build from source, but then you have to maintain things yourself, and you may need additional software anyway to usefully build it.

Comment: Thank you bk2204! My Macbook Pro M1 was provided to me by the company employing me and it does not include XCode IDE. But, I myself installed Visual Studio Code (the version for Mac Silicone) and I suspect that the GIT version installed in my mac (git version 2.32.0 (Apple Git-132)) was installed with VSC (and perhaps not by XCode). Do you think that my version of GIT came with XCode OR with VSC? (thank you)

Comment: If ti says "Apple Git", it's almost certainly XCode or the XCode Developer Tools (which are not XCode, but contain the system compiler and development libraries).  VS Code would not have used that name.